# Getting debugger lisp error: (void-variable w)

Tags: debugging, emacs, evil-mode

Sometimes when I save a file I get a debugger error message in Emacs, it doesn't happen always but happens randomly whenever I save a file. The error message is as follows

```
Debugger entered--Lisp error: (void-variable w)
  eval(w t)
  eval-expression(w nil nil 127)
  funcall-interactively(eval-expression w nil nil 127)
  #<subr call-interactively>(eval-expression nil nil)
  apply(#<subr call-interactively> eval-expression (nil nil))
  call-interactively@ido-cr+-record-current-command(#<subr call-interactively> eval-expression nil nil)
  apply(call-interactively@ido-cr+-record-current-command #<subr call-interactively> (eval-expression nil nil))
  call-interactively(eval-expression nil nil)
  command-execute(eval-expression)
```

This happens whenever I save a file by pressing ":" to invoke the evil mode vim command and following it with "w" for saving the file. Also is there any way of turning off this popup? Even if I cannot find the bug is it possible to disable this pop-up debugger error so it never shows up?

Comment: Is it the case that you're running Emacs in a terminal and typing `ESC` and `:` in quick succession? Emacs could be misinterpreting that as `M-:`, which runs `eval-expression`, because terminals often use the `ESC` character to encode the `Alt` key.

Comment: @Pkkm no, I don't run emacs from a terminal. For some reason I started to see this error very infrequently these days so I don't bother much about it anymore.

Comment: Actually, now that I tried it, it seems that GUI Emacs with default settings does this too. You could try typing `ESC` `:` quickly and see if that lets you reproduce the problem.

Comment: Like I said I barely encounter this nowadays and I don't know which combination of keys causes this. Pressing `ESC`  `:` currently doesn't cause any errors but back in the days it was giving an error when I tried to quickly save by pressing `:w` so I cannot really tell, not that I mind much about the error anymore. I reflexed pressing `ctrl`  `g` as soon as any error pop up so...

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you're maybe hitting a key similar to `:` and getting command `eval-expression`, which tries to evaluate something you type next (such as `w` then `RET`).

I can't speak for Evil's key bindings, but in vanilla Emacs `M-:`, not `:`, is bound in fact to `eval-expression`. (`M-` is `Alt`.)

So if you type `M-: w RET` instead of `: w RET` then that might explain what you see: Emacs tries to evaluate the `w` as a variable, and it's not bound to any value as a variable.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, I do not think I hit "M-: w Ret", I tried to get the same bug today as well but I never pressed the Alt key. Is there any way I can disable the debug-lisp error window to pup up? Or completely disable it?

Comment: You may have hit some other key that Evil binds to `eval-expression`. That's why I said that `M-:` is a *vanilla* Emacs key for that command - dunno what keys Evil uses. You can set variable `debug-on-error` to `nil` to prevent entering a backtrace (but really that should be posted as a separate question).